# adding to json property that may or may not exist yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

let say I want to do this:

```js
  var dashboard = {};
  var page = "index";

  $('.check').click(function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().slideToggle('slow', function() {
        dashboard['pages'][page][$(this).closest('li').attr("id")]['show'] = $(this).is(":hidden") ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded';
    });
  }
```

I get an error saying:

> Dashboard.pages is undefined

Is there away to dynamically add `pages` and the children that follow without having to do the work of checking to see if it is defined first then if it's not doing:

```js
   dashboard['pages'] = {};
```

because sometimes they may already exist and I don't want to have to inspect the tree first I just want to build the branches as needed

**EDIT**
I changed `pagename` to `page` to show that page names will change and also I want to point out that the pages could really be anything too.
The idea is that you have any object that can contain objects with parameters without checking to see if the branches exist

It looks like `$extend` as stated will be the way to go just not sure how that works. Got to get my head around that.

Comment: sorry - the script makes no sense to me. The use of bracket indexers implies the desire to dynamically index the object, but you are using constants. That, combined with the statement that you 'do not want to do the work' has me wondering if _you_ know what you are trying to accomplish. Not trying to denigrate - just an observation as to why you may not get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Better solution for *ES6* here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471690/10405671

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define get and set methods on an `Object`. Actually it could be defined just on the `dashboard` object and only its descendants, but that's easy to do.

```
Object.prototype.get = function(prop) {
    this[prop] = this[prop] || {};
    return this[prop];
};

Object.prototype.set = function(prop, value) {
    this[prop] = value;
}
```

Iterate through nested properties using this `get()` method and call `set()` whenever a value has to be set.

```
var dashboard = {};

dashboard.get('pages').get('user').set('settings', 'oh crap');
// could also set settings directly without using set()
dashboard.get('pages').get('user').settings = 'oh crap';

console.log(dashboard); //​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ {pages: {user: {settings: "oh crap"}}};
```

You could also extend/modify the `get` method to accept the nested properties as individual arguments *or* an array *or* a string. Using that, you'd only have to call get once:

```
// get accepts multiple arguments here
dashboard.get('pages', 'user').set('settings', 'something');

// get accepts an array here
dashboard.get(['pages', 'user']).set('settings', 'something');

// no reason why get can't also accept dotted parameters
// note: you don't have to call set(), could directly add the property
dashboard.get('pages.user').settings = 'something';
```

**Update**:

Since the get method generically returns an object and does not know whether you need an array or some other type of object, so you would have to specify that yourselves:

```
dashboard.get('pages.user').settings = [];
```

Then you could push items to the settings array as

```
dashboard.get('pages.user').settings.push('something');
dashboard.get('pages.user').settings.push('something else');
```

To actually have the get function construct the object hierarchy from a given string such as pages.user, you would have to split the string into parts and check if each nested object exists. Here is a modified version of `get` that does just that:

```
Object.prototype.get = function(prop) {
    var parts = prop.split('.');
    var obj = this;
    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var p = parts[i];
        if(obj[p] === undefined) {
            obj[p] = {};
        }
        obj = obj[p];
    }
    return obj;
}

// example use
var user = dashboard.get('pages.user');
user.settings = [];
user.settings.push('something');
user.settings.push('else');

console.log(dashboard); // {pages: {user: {settings: ["something", "else"] }}}

// can also add to settings directly
dashboard.get('pages.user.settings').push('etc');
```

Comment: ok this looks like what I was asking for except that I'm not using prototype how would I do this in jquery ? also let me take it just a step further lets say I want to do it so I have 
dashboard.get('pages.user.settings').push("something");
dashboard.get('pages.user.settings').push("somethingelse");
that should give me two items in settings right ?

Comment: @mmcgrail, this is regular Javascript and not the Prototype framework. The first approach of getting each property should work on every browser (jquery is not needed for that). Updating the answer for the other query.

Comment: I would caution against blindly adding to `Object`'s prototype in this manner.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it with the ternary operator:

```
dashboard['pages'][page] = dashboard['pages'][page] ? dashboard['pages'][page] : {};
```

That will do the trick no matter if it's set/null or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good builtin way to do this, but you could always abstract it with a function.

```
function getProperty(obj,prop){
    if( typeof( obj[prop] ) == 'undefined' ){
        obj[prop] = {};
    }
    return obj[prop];
}
```

Then you use

`getProperty(dashboard,'pages')['pagename']`

or

```
getProperty(getProperty(dashboard,'pages'),'pagename');
```

As mentioned, $.extend will make this less burdensome.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for my case was to do a Object prototype

```
 /**
 * OBJECT GET
 * Used to get an object property securely
 * @param object
 * @param property
 * @returns {*}
 */
Object.get = function(object, property) {
    var properties = property.split('.');
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        if (object && object[properties[i]]) {
            object = object[properties[i]];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return object;
};
```

And then you can get your property like this

```
var object = { step1: { step2: { step3: ['value1', 'value2'] }}}
Object.get(object, 'step1.step2.step3'); // ['value1', 'value2']
Object.get(object, 'step1.step2.step3.0'); // 'value1'
Object.get(object, 'step1.step2.step3.step4'); // null
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

$.extend is the way to go

```
function elem(a,b){
var r={'pages':{'pagename':{}}};
r.pages.pagename[a]={'show':b};
return r;
}
data={};
//inside the event handler or something:
data = $.extend(true,data,elem($(this).closest('li').attr("id"),$(this).is(":hidden") ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded'));
```

But honestly - this is a rather messy idea to store this information anyway.
I bet that if You need that information later it could be done with a good selector or with jQuery.data()

Comment: but that's not dynamic your defining the json in the function. I'll look into the other suggestions you have

Comment: Nope, I'm building an object that has only one element and merge it into the data variable. It does the same thing Your code did if it worked, but also works when Your code didn't. Still I'm glad You try a different way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = dashboard['pages'] || {};
foo['pagename'] = 'your thing here';
dashboard['pages'] = foo;
```

Explaining: the first line will check if the first value is null, undefined or... false (don't think this is a problem here): if it is, create a new object, if it is not, will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you need this:

```
var dashBoard = new Array();
if(!dashboard['page123']) {
    dashBoard.push('page123');
} else {
...do what you want
}
```

Seems you are dealing with XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you use underscore >= 1.9.0, you can use [`property`](https://underscorejs.org/#property) and [`propertyOf`](https://underscorejs.org/#propertyOf):

```
d={a: {b: "c"}}
_.property(["a", "b", "c", "e"])(d)   // undefined
_.property(["a", "b"])(d)             // "c"
_.propertyOf(d)(["a", "b", "c", "e"]) // undefined
_.propertyOf(d)(["a", "b"])           // "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

This method from my tiny object utility library answer the question asked by @mcgrailm in his comment of the marked answer:
**Question**
dashboard.get('pages.user.settings').push("something"); dashboard.get('pages.user.settings').push("somethingelse")
**Answer**

```js
const users = {
    0:{
      name:"John",
      age:30,
      car:null,
      job: "Developer",
      address: "Dakar",
      interest: {
        music: ["rnb", "rap"],
        sports: ["football", "basketball"],
        food: [
          {
            senegal: {0:"yassa", 1:"mafé"},
            mali: ["yassa", "mafé", "jolof rice"]
          },
          {
            usa: ["burger", "nuggets", 
              [
                {jfr:["jfr_sn", "jfr_ng"]}
              ]
            ]
          },
          {
            italia: ["pizza", "peperoni"]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    1:{
      name:"Jane",
      age:20,
      car:null,
      job: "attorney",
      address: "Dakar",
      interest: {
        music: ["rnb", "rap"],
        sports: ["football", "basketball"],
        language: ["deutch", "english"]
      }
    },
    2:{
      name:"Moussa",
      age:26,
      car:null,
      job: "plice officer",
      address: "Dakar",
      interest: {
        music: ["rnb", "rap", "trap"],
        sports: ["basketball", "handball"],
        countries: {
          Africa: ["Senegal", "Rwanda", "Morroco"],
          Europe: ["England", "Russia"],
          Asia: ["China", "Saudi Arabia", "Palestine"],
          America: ["Brasil", "Mexico", "USA"],
          Oceania: ["Australia"]
        }
      }
    }
}

/*In this example we are using our users object declared previously and we are tryin to access the jfr key
by using the path that leads to this key
*/
//using vanilla js
let result1 = users[0].interest.food[1].usa[2][0].jfr

//using this library
let result2 = _Object(users).getEntryByPath("0.interest.food.1.usa.2.0.jfr")

//expected output for both method
[ "jfr_sn", "jfr_ng" ]
```

more utility visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/spicy_object