# React + Typescript + GraphQL: what to do with null

Tags: reactjs, typescript

GraphQL queries return a type or null. I'm having trouble coming up with a clean way to handle all these nulls cleanly...

if I have a big nested graphql query...

```
query {
  markdown {
    authors {
      names {
        first 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then each of those fields is nullable up to the top, so then in my TSX file I would have to check those somehow, but how to do it cleanly?

```
const Component = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
   {data && data.markdown && data.markdown.authors && data.markdown.authors.names && data.markdown.authors.names.first}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Too bad optional chaining is not yet a thing, otherwise that's what I would have suggested. `data?.markdown?.authors?.names?.first` anyone? I thought typescript had this feature and it was called `elvis operator`, but it seems I may have misread that

Comment: I saw your initial answer and I got excited but it doesn't work like that I think. It only works in declarations as far as I know

Comment: See this other answer which suggests a way of making use of this operator through babel. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41897688/2089675

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lodash, you can use the methods `_.get` and `_.has` to determine if the data object has the deeply nested key.

```
const data = {a: {b: {c: 'nested data'}}}
_.get(data, 'a.b.c') // returns 'nested data'
```

Also see answers to the following questions for other approaches.

1. [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/4534179)
2. [adding to json property that may or may not exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2525943/4534179)